# LINQ To SQL does not work when adding new object

Tags: linq-to-sql

I use the following code to insert a new record to my Users table:

```
    public bool CreateUser(User obj)
    {
        obj.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (_db = new CMSDataContext())
        {
            obj.SiteId = SiteID;
            _db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
            _db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I do not get any errors, and everything seems fine. I can read a record from database with same DataContext. But after the above method runs completely, I see nothing new in my Users table. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Is the id column truly a PK in the sql server database?

Comment: I found it finally.I sent username with null value, and I did not put appropriate message in exception to handle it.